# How create a java project for both intellij and eclipse ide's

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, project

I would like to create a java project but be able to open the project in both eclipse and intellij IDE's, could someone please point me in the right direction on how to setup a project in either ide but able to open in both.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A Maven project can be opened by both these IDE's and also by others (like Netbeans).